# How to assert if converter is applied on a type using Fluent Assertions

Tags: unit-testing, automapping, fluent-assertions

I need to apply some complex logic for creating map so i have used custom type converter as below:

```
cfg.CreateMap<ConsumerRequest,IEnumerable<ProviderRequest>>().ConvertUsing<RequestConverter>();
```

I am using fluentassertions in unit testing and want to assert that ConsumerRequest has RequestConverter applied but not sure how to do it, I think I should be able to right an extension method which will assert the same with some message but not sure how to achieve this, any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a extension method on IMapper as below:

```
public static AutoMapperTypeConverterAssertions<TDestinationModel>ForType<TDestinationModel>(this IMapper subject)
{
  return new AutoMapperTypeConverterAssertions<TDestinationModel>(subject);
}

public class AutoMapperTypeConverterAssertions<TDestinationModel> : ReferenceTypeAssertions<object, AutoMapperTypeConverterAssertions<TDestinationModel>>
{
   public AutoMapperTypeConverterAssertions(object subject)
   {            
     Subject = subject;
   }

   protected override string Context => "auto mapper type converter";

   public AndConstraint<AutoMapperTypeConverterAssertions<TDestinationModel>> ShouldHaveTypeConverterApplied<TSourceModel, TConverterType>(
    string because = "", params object[] becauseArgs)
   {            
      var mapper = Subject as IMapper;
      var foundTypeInConfig = mapper
        .ConfigurationProvider
        .FindTypeMapFor<TSourceModel, TDestinationModel>()
        .TypeConverterType;

      Execute.Assertion
         .BecauseOf(because, becauseArgs)
         .ForCondition(foundTypeInConfig == typeof(TConverterType))
         .FailWith("Expected the mapping for {0} to contain {1} AutoMapper   Type Converter, but was not found.", typeof(TDestinationModel).Name,   typeof(TConverterType).Name);

  }
return new     AndConstraint<AutoMapperTypeConverterAssertions<TDestinationModel>>(this);


}
```

Comment: By using this a can easily assert if a converter is applied on type or not